# AngularJS RouteProvider not working correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$routeProvider.when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'index.php/projects/projects/contact',
    controller: 'home'
});

$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
```

I cannot seem to get the templateUrl to pull in the correct URL. It seems to only redirect back to /home. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does your server respond correctly to `index.php/projects/projects/contact`, or is it redirecting you to /home?

You might also check that the request isn't actually asking for /home/index.php/... if you're using html5mode

Comment: I wouldn't use $routeProvider as it's pretty terrible.  Take a look at angular-ui-router which gives $stateProvider and $state to use in place of $route and $routeProvider.  It's a much more robust system which allows for greater complexity.  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Comment: I've worked on the code a little bit and now my app just freezes.

Answer (score 0):

Please show your working directory structure. I think templateUrl should not include `index.php`. Try,

```
$routeProvider.when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'projects/projects/contact.html',
    controller: 'home'
});

$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yor Calling path, `index.php/projects/projects/contact`,  may be wrong.
Just use `projects/projects/contact/index.php`.

The code can also be simplified as follows, instead of calling `$routeProvider` twice.

```
$routeProvider.
when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'projects/projects/contact/index.php',
    controller: 'home'
}).
otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/home'
})
```